# Puppet command does not start stop service in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet

service{'cron':
ensure => 'running',
enable => 'true',
}

Error:
change from 'running' to 'stopped' failed: systems stop for cron failed.

Comment: That error message seems to be for a different resource.

Comment: Have you tried a "systemctl start cron" and a "systemctl status cron" to see if there is something in its configuration that is stopping it from starting?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

Drop this

```
service { 'crond':
  ensure   => 'running',
  enable   => 'true',
}
```

Into a file on a server, let's call the file `crontest.pp` then as root run `puppet apply crontest.pp` you should see cron start.

Also, if you're trying to debug this sort of thing a good starting place is to use `puppet resource` in this case `puppet resource service`, you should be able to see a list of all your services. Look through that to find the one relating to cron, it gives you the Puppet code for it's current state so you can copy that directly into a class file, just ignore the `provider =>`  line as the Puppet resource abstraction layer will take care of that.